# Ubuntu 14.04 32bit.iso will not load, at all, from KINGSTON usb

Tags: usb-installation

My computer doesn't seem to be capable of using this on a USB stick. Am I missing something here? I've followed all instructions i can find for using a USB drive but my computer will not load the .iso file at all. Am I supposed to convert it or what?

Comment: What is your mean _my computer will not load the .iso file_?

Comment: What OS are you using, what is the problem, what have you tried, etc? http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows and want to install Ubuntu via USB stick flash drive it's here [Installation/FromUSBStickQuick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick). Or not if you just to create a bootable USB stick it's here [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to copy the .iso file onto the pen drive. If you are on Windows follow http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows. If on Ubuntu use Startup Disk Creator that comes bundled with Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to load your iso to the USB stick. It makes USB Bootable of a lof kinds of OSes(include Windows, Linux, and more). I tried to make LiveUSB with a lot of tools, but this tool works perfect.